# opening playground directly without navgating through xcode

Tags: swift, xcode

I play around with the playground a lot and write most of my coding exercises there, is there a way to directly open the playground like an app or with some shortcut

Comment: You mean like double-click on the file in Finder?

Comment: You can just use spotlight search to open your project

Answer (score 0):

Playgrounds run in Xcode. There is a "Swift Playgrounds" app for iPad that lets you work with Playgrounds on iPad.

Those are the two apps in which you can run playgrounds. Full stop.

For playgrounds you develop on a Mac, you can double-click the playground file in the Finder and Xcode will launch and open the playground, but you must use Xcode to build and run the playground.